# Blender and Linux, Which Linux distrubution is best for Blender 2.81

Tags: linux, hardware

I just bought parts to build a computer for Blender, a Ryzen 7 3800m and RTX 2070 and 32 gb 3200 ram. I want the best OS for running Blender with that system. I understand Linux is the OS that allows blender to work the best. There are so many different Linux distributions though. Which one is best for Blender 2.81?

Comment: Hi Janet. Have voted to close as "primarily opinion based" as is with questions like this "best" can turn into a debate over linux flavours.  Sigh, My system is seriously under-powered in relation to your specs.  FWIW I build blender  on  Ubuntu 18. Ubuntu repos can be notoriously slow to upgrade software to new versions. Can tailor a build to your system. Building blender isn't for everyone. Builds downloaded from blender.org have given me no issues.

Comment: The best Linux distribution for you is the one you're comfortable working with. Blender doesn't really care. If you've never used Linux before and aren't familiar with working on the command line, then I'd suggest something that has a nice UI and doesn't require a lot of tinkering to get things working right. For that I would recommend Ubuntu.

Comment: Although I agree with @batFINGER, I think the prevailing opinion will be unanimous. As possibly bourne out through the comments here.  I have posted an answer to this because I thought there were some good reasons to cover.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux then go for one with the best support.  That would, without doubt, be Ubuntu ... the user base is so large that it is really easy to find help.

There is a dedicated Stack Exchange site at https://askubuntu.com/ if you like to search these Q&A sites.

I believe they use(d) Ubuntu at the blender institute, certainly I have have seen it in some of their videos.

It is also popular among blender users.  This screenshot comes from https://snapcraft.io ( Snaps are an app package format, which is officially supported by Blender).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSaCg.png]

While these stats may be biased (more Ubuntu users will use Snap than other distros), it does show that you would at least have some company.

Once you are comfortable with it, you will find it easier to migrate to other variants many of which are based on Ubuntu, so it is hard to avoid.

Reading this article on [best linux distributions for everyone](https://itsfoss.com/best-linux-distributions/), all but one are based on Ubuntu.

**DISCLAIMER: I don't currently use Ubuntu**

... but then again I have 20+ yrs experience with linux and like to edit text files.  I have used Ubuntu for long periods, over the years.  It is probably your best start point.